# How to set validation if form is valid on click on checkbox?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

This is little bit confusing to me. I have one form which has two parts are there.

1. personal details
2. address (it should be validated once the panel has to open/close using checkbox)

I am using angular v4 and reactive form.

```
this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      title: ['', [Validators.required]],
      address: this.fb.group({
        addressline1: [''],
        addressline2: [''],
        area: [''],
        zipcode: [''],
        city: [''],
        country: [''],
        state: ['']
      })
    });
```

Once the checkbox for address is clicked , I have to say these are mandatory fields, please input the value and on close/unchecked errors should be close.

I have tried like this :

```
onAddressCheck() {
    if (this.registerForm.controls.address.valid) {
      this.registerForm.controls.address.get('addressline1').setValidators(Validators.required);  
    } else {
      alert("form is not valid.");
    }
  }
```

and in template :

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="permanent_addr_chkbx" (change)="onAddressCheck()" />
    <font color="white">Address</font>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="form-group collapse" id="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
  <input type="text" formControlName="addressline1">
  <p *ngIf="registerForm.get('permanent_address.addressline1').errors">This is required</p>
</div>

<p *ngIf="!addressline1.errors.required">This is required</p> // earlier i was using this.
```

but not getting anything.

So how to do that I am not getting any idea ? Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Ever heard of *ngIf?

Comment: @VinodBhavnani yes dude, Can you check again ? just i have updated with some code.

Comment: Perhaps the way you access the form error object is not the right one.
Have you tried: 
`<*ngIf="registerForm.get('address.addressLine1').errors">This is required</p>` ?
Here's a link to the docs: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#inspect-formcontrol-properties

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously something that is going to depend on your checkbox. Say you have a property `showErrors: boolean` and your template has a section where you show these errors -  or classes or similar.

You can have a method that responds to checkboxChange and flips this flag. And depending on the staet of the flag, your errors will either be shown or not.

Comment: Can you check my query ? Just i have updated with code. Where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you also add part of the template where this checkbox is?

Comment: Now, added template too.

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate your form once your checkbox is set to true :

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
    title: ['', [Validators.required]]
  });
}

handleClickOnAddressCheckbox() {
  if (this.myCheckboxValue) {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      title: ['', [Validators.required]],
      address: this.fb.group({
        addressline1: [''],
        addressline2: [''],
        area: [''],
        zipcode: [''],
        city: [''],
        country: [''],
        state: ['']
      })
    });
  } else {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      title: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }
}
```

And you will have to hide your fields in your HTML for when your checkbox isn't checked.